# Issue on saving the XML file after editing it

Tags: c#, .net, xml-parsing

I have an XML file with some data on it..for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CreateAndSendMessageRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns="http://schemas.communisis.com/lv">
<CompositionRequest>
<Metadata xmlns="http://lv.com/gi/si/common/CommonTypes">
<PolicyReference>250028766505DN</PolicyReference>
<AccountReference>Test1234</AccountReference>
<QuoteReference>Test3214</QuoteReference>
<OutboundTransactionID>string</OutboundTransactionID>
</Metadata>
```

Now i want to replace POLICY REFERENCE value with some dummy data. I am able to do that but now i have to save it as a new file with a different file name..
How can i achieve that..
For reference i am giving my code.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filepath);
XmlNodeList node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("PolicyReference");
var item =node.Item(0);
string value = item.FirstChild.Value;
string nevalue = value.Replace(value, "Test123");
doc.DocumentElement.;
doc.Save(@"C:\Test\file.xml");
```

Comment: You are just doing it ...

Comment: The value is not getting replaced..@MarcoSalerno

Comment: You replaced the string, but you have to write that back to the `doc` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml wasn't valid.

Anyway, this is how to make it work:

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CreateAndSendMessageRequest>
<CompositionRequest>
<Metadata xmlns="http://lv.com/gi/si/common/CommonTypes">
<PolicyReference>250028766505DN</PolicyReference>
<AccountReference>Test1234</AccountReference>
<QuoteReference>Test3214</QuoteReference>
<OutboundTransactionID>string</OutboundTransactionID>
</Metadata>
</CompositionRequest>
</CreateAndSendMessageRequest>
```

Code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("bho.xml");
XmlNodeList node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("PolicyReference");
node[0].InnerText = "Test123";
doc.Save("file.xml");
```

Result xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CreateAndSendMessageRequest>
  <CompositionRequest>
    <Metadata xmlns="http://lv.com/gi/si/common/CommonTypes">
      <PolicyReference>Test123</PolicyReference>
      <AccountReference>Test1234</AccountReference>
      <QuoteReference>Test3214</QuoteReference>
      <OutboundTransactionID>string</OutboundTransactionID>
    </Metadata>
  </CompositionRequest>
</CreateAndSendMessageRequest>
```

Hope it helps you ^^

Comment: Thats great...Thanks a Ton @Marco Salemo